# fscanf() code does not always crash memory, but sometimes

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, scanf, coredump

=========================

## code (file name is test.c)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[] ) {
    int i=0, num=atoi(argv[1]);
    char **arr=(char**)malloc(num*sizeof(char*));
    FILE  *fp = fopen("test.txt","r");
    if( arr == NULL) { printf("out of memory\n"); exit(1); }
    if( fp == NULL) { printf("cannot open the file \n"); exit(1); }

    for(i=0; i< num; i++) fscanf(fp,"%s", arr+i ); // HERE
    printf("%s\n", arr+num-1 );

    fclose(fp);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

========

## test.txt

```
watermelon
grape
strawberries
orange
peach
banana
mango
cherry
pineapple
apple
blueberry
raspberry
pear
melon
greengrapes
tangerine
kiwifruit
pomegranate
plum
nectarine
```

========

## Question

when i excuted below several times

```
test 1
test 2
...
...
test 7
test 8
```

it crushes often something like "core dump" but working as i expected.

however, when i type higher than 9, it never crush...

```
test 9
test 10
...
```

[image]

what makes this code crash?

Comment: FYI: If your code actually crushed something, you'd have a lot more to worry about. The word you want is _crash_ ;)

Comment: i am sorry about crush, i meant crash,

Comment: @alexparkjw Then why did you not fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = 0, num = atoi(argv[1]);
    char** arr = (char**)malloc(num * sizeof(char*));
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        arr[j] = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    }
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (; i < num; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", arr[i]);
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < num; k++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

for `fscanf(fp, "%s", arr[i]);`, you need alloc memory for each `arr[i]`.

Comment: There is no `new` in C. And even it were C++, you do not want to `free()` what had been allocated using `new`, but use `delete`.

Comment: Ok, as you decided for C, the casting of `malloc()` got useless.

Answer (score 4):

`fscanf` is trying to write data into `*arr[i]` which you haven't allocated. You only allocated `arr[i]` (which you didn't initialize either).

Comment: Yes, it's an array of uninitalized pointers.  Those string could be written to anywhere in memory.

Comment: hard to understand for me. can you least tell me "how?" ,please~!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, you only allocated space for pointers, but not for the strings themselves. Here is an alternative to other answers, if you are programming for a POSIX.1-2008 compatible platform or with new enough *glibc* (such as a recent Linux, probably also MinGW):

You can use `a` specifier for `%s` conversion (read more at [`scanf` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)), which causes `scanf` to allocate memory for the string (which the caller is responsible of calling `free()` on), so for your code:

```
// No need to cast return value of malloc or calloc.
// Optional: switched to calloc, which has overhead of zeroing memory,
// but also makes immediate segfault more likely on some bugs.
char **arr = calloc(num, sizeof(char*));
//...
for(i=0; i < num; i++) {
    int status = fscanf(fp,"%ms", arr[i] );
    assert(status==1); // really simple error checking added
}
```

And as said, when done, you should free the allocated memory:

```
for(i=0; i < num; i++) {
    free(arr[i]);
}
free(arr);
```

The benefit is, you don't need to worry about buffer overflow (if the file is bigger than available virtual memory, then you will be in trouble though, unless you add a limit to `a` specifier, read the man page for details...) and you don't waste any memory by having too much space allocated for strings that are shorter. The downside is that `a` specifier is not defined by C standard, so it will reduce portability of your code to GNU and POSIX platforms, and could cause your teacher to reject it (if it is coursework), in case that matters.